# Bootstrap 4 delete button changed to weird shape after form submit

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-4

i have a panel in a page, and in the panel header i have a red delete btn, the panel content contains a form which has a few btns (the red delete btn is not in the form, but its linked to the form via the form="abc" attribute).

in the pic below, When i click the btns in the form, it'll post some values. Before i submit a form (the pink remind button), my red delete button looks like this ( nice and rounded)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lDEI.png)

but after submit, it became out of shape. ( btn height changed). This only happens after i submit and didnt reload the page, if i reload the page or redirect the page back to itself, then the delete btn will return to its normal shape.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw4o6.png)

i did not alter the classes of the btns using js or jq, the only thing that happens after i submit are some php scripts which shouldnt affect aesthetics. Also, the panel is reloaded every 5 seconds within the page to update its content, but the whole page itself is not reloaded, so if its html or bs4 issue, then after i submit form, the delete btn should return to normal shape after 5 sec, but it seems like something outside of the panels but within the page needs to be reloaded to change the delete btn back to normal shape. I checked the deletebtn and the parent elements in inspect before submit, after submit, and after reload page, but everything is the same, except that it shows the height px are different.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post snippet of your code?

Alternatively just give inline style attribute to the button and specify height, width, padding etc.